# how to authenticate googleaccount in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gdata-api

how to authenticate googleaccount in iphone ?
in my app. i import gdata(gmap)services properly through this link(http://www.johntwang.com/blog/2009/06/08/how-to-use-google-apis-with-iphone-sdk/) next step i want to access my gmail account (showing map) i have no way ?